# Corrupted Collection Database after an unsuccessful TFS 2015 "update 2" to "update 3" upgrade process

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I've upgraded an On-Premise TFS instance from 2015 update 2 to update 3. the process failed for some reason (I think it was related to user permission to alter db schema - ddl).

Now the DB is corrupted, the TFS admin console "thinks" the DB is ready for TFS 2015 update 3 but i get an error trying to query for work items in the web portal.

```
Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'.
```

Is there a way do downgrade the schema?

Is there a way to 'trick' the DB to be in "update 2" state so the upgrade process will run again?

Any way to recover my work items? I don't mind copying them to a new collection or team project.

Thanks.

The DB's extended properties are:

```
TFS_DATABASE_TYPE Collection
TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 14.0.23128.0
TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015
TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL Dev14.M102
```

and the Configuration DB's extended properties are:

```
TFS_DATABASE_TYPE Configuration
TFS_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE OnPremises
TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION 14.102.25423.0
TFS_SCHEMA_VERSION Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 3
TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL Dev14.M102
```

**EDIT**
After using SQL Profiler I was ending up changing one of TFS's Views:

[vw_denorm_WorkItemCoreLatest.sql](https://gist.github.com/myGuruPitka/9a3adf18e7f2cd5795b69cdc47d583d0)

If anyone have figured it out please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating TFS Data Warehouse and Analysis Services by following this article: [Rebuild TFS Warehouse and Analysis Databases From Scratch](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20113.rebuild-tfs-warehouse-and-analysis-databases-from-scratch.aspx).

Comment: Thank you!
should I try that even tough i'm not using reporting & analysis service at the moment?

Comment: @guruPitka Yes, otherwise it may cause some other issue.